# my do-while loop seems to be running forever even though i change the value of the condition

Tags: java, variables, nested-loops, do-while

```
    boolean onGoing = true;
    do {
        String p1 = "playing";
        while (p1.equals("playing")) {
            System.out.println("Player 1, enter hit row/column:");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            if (a >= 0 && a < 5 && b >= 0 && b < 5) {
                if (history1[a][b] == '-') {
                    p1 += " no more";
                    if (board2[a][b] == '@') {
                        history1[a][b] = 'X';
                        board2[a][b] = 'X';
                        String status = check(board2);
                        if (status.equals("win")) {
                            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 WINS! YOU SUNK ALL OF YOUR OPPONENT'S SHIPS!");
                            onGoing = false;
                            printBattleShip(board1);
                            printBattleShip(board2);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 HIT PLAYER 2's SHIP!");
                        }
                    } else if (board2[a][b] == '-') {
                        System.out.println("PLAYER 1 MISSED!");
                        history1[a][b] = 'O';
                        board2[a][b] = 'O';
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You already fired on this spot. Choose different coordinates.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
            }
        }
        String p2 = "playing";
        while (p2.equals("playing")) {
            System.out.println("Player 2, enter hit row/column:");
            int c = sc.nextInt();
            int d = sc.nextInt();
            if (c >= 0 && c < 5 && d >= 0 && d < 5) {
                if (history2[c][d] == '-') {
                    p2 += " no more";
                    if (board1[c][d] == '@') {
                        history2[c][d] = 'X';
                        board1[c][d] = 'X';
                        String status = check(board1);
                        if (status.equals("win")) {
                            System.out.println("PLAYER 2 WINS! YOU SUNK ALL OF YOUR OPPONENT'S SHIPS!");
                            onGoing = false;
                            printBattleShip(board2);
                            printBattleShip(board1);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("PLAYER 2 HIT PLAYER 1's SHIP!");
                        }
                    } else if (board1[c][d] == '-') {
                        history2[c][d] = 'O';
                        board1[c][d] = 'O';
                        System.out.println("PLAYER 2 MISSED!");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You already fired on this spot. Choose different coordinates.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
            }
        }
    } while (onGoing);

private static String check(char[][] arr1) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i][j] == '@') {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sum == 0) {
        return "win";
    } else {
        return "keep playing";
    }
}
```

// I declared and initialized a boolean variable called ongoing before a do-while loop. Then I create a while loop inside the do while loop. And inside the while loop, there are a series of conditional statement. Eventually, I changed the value of the boolean variable and feed it back to the while statement, letting it evaluate it. But it doesn't seem to change the value. Is it because the scope of the variable? How can I fix it?

edit: check method added

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Btw. the problem might be in `check()` method, which you didn't post.

Comment: what is the input to your code? where does it keep looping? player1/player2?